# Method to change position within the Legacy GridLayout

Tags: java, android

I have a GridLayout with 4 Buttons in it. I want to change the positions of the Buttons within the GridLayout (from row 0 / column 0 to row 1 / column 1 for example). Is there a method in Java, which can do that?

I have already tried to change the Id's of the Buttons, but it didn't work.

[image: my gui]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/grdlyt"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="182dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:columnCount="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:rowCount="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_f1_a1"
            android:layout_width="202dp"
            android:layout_height="88dp"
            android:onClick="f1a1Clicked"
            android:text="Affalterbach"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="0" />
```